# how to align equations in aligned equations (or statements)

Tags: align

Ok so I want to create something like the one in the attached picture. Since whenever I tried to use align command for it, I ended up having equations in weird positions, I gave up and used \textcolor{white}{} to push some statements. I want to be able to do that with proper code but I don't seem to be able to do that. Can anyone help?[image]

```
\begin{align*}
|Tf_1(x) - Tf_2(x)| & = \left| \left( \int_{a}^{x}f_1(t) \,dt  + g(x) \right)  \left( \int_{a}^{x} f_2(t) \,dt + g(x) \right) \right|& \\ \\
& = \left| \int_{a}^{x} f_1(t) \,dt - \int_{a}^{x} f_2(t) \,dt \right| & \\ \\
& \leq \int_{a}^{x} |f_1(t) - f_2(t)| \,dt \stackrel{\star}{\leq} \int_{a}^{x} \max_{t \in [a, b]}{|f_1(t) - f_2(t)|} = \varphi (f_1 , f_2 ) . \int_{a}^{x} \,dt & \\
&\textcolor{white}{lllllllllllllllllllllkllllllllllllllllllllllkllllllllllllllklqqq} = \varphi (f_1 , f_2) (x -a)& \\
&\textcolor{white}{lllllllllllllllllllllkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllklqqq} \leq (b - a) \varphi (f_1 , f_2) &
\end{align*}
```

Comment: you image appears to show inequalities not `\iff` (⇔) ?

Comment: the sign doesn't matter, sorry for not clearly stating that. (I usually try it for iffs but this was the one I could find first) My problem is how to align the equations.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't forget to add a minus sign in the first row. :⁠-⁠)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you embed an `aligned` environment inside an `align*` environment.

[image]

I trust you know how to replace `aaaaa`, `bbbbb`, etc with expressions you're actually interested in. :-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" and "aligned" environments
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
aaaaa 
&=   bbbbb \\
&=   ccccc \\
&\le ddddd \le eeeee
   \begin{aligned}[t]
      &=   ggggg \\
      &=   hhhhh \\
      &\le kkkkk \,.
   \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! I have been going nuts about this. I suck when it comes to coding and I started learning Latex like 10 days ago. I will be forever thankful.

Comment: what do you have against ffffffffffff ? :-)

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here's the full display, with some changes:

1. I removed the trailing `&` that serve no purpose (and are possibly harmful);
2. I generally prefer manually sized delimiters, although in this particular case `\left` and `\right` do the same choice;
3. `\max` doesn't take an argument: you type `\max_{t\in[a,b]} f(t)`, not `\max_{t\in[a,b]}{f(t)}`;
4. there was a missing “dt”;
5. there is a period that possibly would denote multiplication, but is very unusual (and anyway redundant in this case);
6. don't do `\\ \\`, but use the space specifier `\\[2ex]` (choose the right amount of space);
7. in general, `\overset` works better than `\stackrel` (and has clearer meaning);
8. the last line should be slightly moved down.

I also provide an alternative version that fits in the standard text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
|Tf_1(x) - Tf_2(x)| 
& = \biggl|
      \biggl(\int_{a}^{x} f_1(t) \,dt + g(x)\biggr)
      \biggl(\int_{a}^{x} f_2(t) \,dt + g(x)\biggr)
    \biggr|
\\[2ex]
& = \biggl| \int_{a}^{x} f_1(t) \,dt - \int_{a}^{x} f_2(t) \,dt \biggr|
\\[2ex]
& \leq \int_{a}^{x} |f_1(t) - f_2(t)| \,dt 
  \overset{*}{\leq} \int_{a}^{x} \max_{t \in [a, b]}|f_1(t) - f_2(t)| \,dt
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  & = \varphi (f_1 , f_2 ) \int_{a}^{x} \,dt \\
  & = \varphi (f_1 , f_2) (x -a) \\[1.5ex]
  & \leq (b - a) \varphi (f_1 , f_2)
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
|Tf_1(x) - Tf_2(x)| 
& = \biggl|
      \biggl(\int_{a}^{x} f_1(t) \,dt + g(x)\biggr)
      \biggl(\int_{a}^{x} f_2(t) \,dt + g(x)\biggr)
    \biggr|
\\[2ex]
& = \biggl| \int_{a}^{x} f_1(t) \,dt - \int_{a}^{x} f_2(t) \,dt \biggr|
\\[2ex]
& \leq \int_{a}^{x} |f_1(t) - f_2(t)| \,dt 
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  & \overset{*}{\leq} \int_{a}^{x} \max_{t \in [a, b]}|f_1(t) - f_2(t)|\,dt \\
  & = \varphi (f_1 , f_2 ) \int_{a}^{x} \,dt \\
  & = \varphi (f_1 , f_2) (x -a) \\[1.5ex]
  & \leq (b - a) \varphi (f_1 , f_2)
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possible improvement, for the sake of clarity, would be to put the two “g(x)” in front of the integrals.

Comment: wow thanks! unfortunately i might forget some stuff but I am not really allowed to change any because my teacher requests me not to. My coding is like code version of cavemen speech, I know. thanks for rescuing me from butchering it!